# XPages Repeat control vs View Control Perfomance

Tags: xpages

Does anybody have any idea whether there any performance differences between using a repeat control or view control.

I am specifically looking at displaying a few columns from a view containing a large number of records; i'm not getting any performance issues just wondering if one perfoms better than another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you bind a view to a repeat, the internal code uses a ViewNavigator object. This means that there is no difference in performance between using a view control and using a repeat control bound to a view.

There is a difference in usage since a view control MUST be bound to a view, where a repeat control can be bound to lots of different things such as anything that's an array, or a Java Collection, or a lotus.domino collection, or all kinds of SSJS return types.

(Thanks to Nathan Freeman for help with the answer).

Comment: I know I am a little late on this one, but which would be faster - View/Repeat control bound to view or Repeat control bound to collection/array?